# Why does Firefox not use CSS from an local absolute path?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a local HTML file which has a link to a local CSS file. Both files are on machine A. The HTML is in one location but the CSS is stored elsewhere on machine A. The HTML file is a report generated by a program running on machine A. The user reads the HTML report on machine A.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My very first html document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\tmp\folder1\css\mystyle.css"  />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="myclass" >Hello World!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS** mystyle.css

```
.myclass {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

The folder structure is like so:

```
C:
+
+->tmp
     +
     +>folder1
     |       +
     |       +>css
     |           +
     |           +>mystyle.css
     +>folder2
             +
             +>index.html
```

In Firefox the CSS is not applied. The results from Firefox, Chrome, IE, Edge (clockwise).
[image]

Version of Firefox: 63.0.3 (64bit)

**What I have tried**

1. Relative path to the CSS (href="../folder1/css/mystyle.css" ). This works.
2. Changed from forward slash to backward slash, escaped slashes. This did not work.

I would prefer the absolute path for the CSS.
I would prefer not to copy the CSS.

**Questions**

1. Can someone explain why Firefox does not apply the CSS?
2. What is a quick fix for  this problem?
3. What is the right-thing-to-do?

Comment: Probably security related. The quick fix is probably the relative path you already provided yourself or setup a (localhost) webserver to run your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Firefox has no access to your filesystem for obvious security reason (see [this kb post for more infos](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work) ) .
2. There are many possible workaround if you'd like to keep your css file on a different location, the most popular one being webpack or any other build system. Basically every modern front end development stack uses it. It is a node.js tool that will gather all your static assets using preconfigured path and "bundle them" in a local build.
3. If it is just a single css file for a single use-case, just use a relative path (or a `file:///` prefixed path). The best solution here is obviously the quickest and easiest.

Answer (score 3):

Prepend file:// to the href of your css link and it will work. I just tried it myself using your folder structure. It originally didn't work in Firefox as reported but it did work in Chrome. Prepending file:// allows it to work on both.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file://C:/tmp/folder1/css/mystyle.css"  />
```